# How to make carousel like swipe on stacked cards?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to put stack cards on a center view of flutter container.
Which I am trying to have carousel like swipe or slider only left to right or right to left. On right to left the next card will come up and swipe left to right the prvious card will come back. Something like [example link to animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDjyA.jpg)

So far, I have gotten the desired view with `Stack` and `Positioned` widgets. Now how do I make the slide or animate look like the example?

So far tried to do it with draggable, which is dragging to all around, which is not the behaviour I am looking for. Then I looked at `PageView` which will not work with `Positioned` widget as they are expected to be under `Stack`. So at the moment I am not sure how to do this? Any guide or example would be really helpful, as ***I just started flutter a week now***.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/images/group_6.svg',
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Text(
                  'My cool Header',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                      fontSize: Constants.height / 70,
                      fontFamily: 'Exo2',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 13,
            child: Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  right: (sizingInformation.screenSize.width * 0.09),
                  left: (sizingInformation.screenSize.width * 0.21),
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    elevation: 10.0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: (sizingInformation.screenSize.height * 0.5),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: sizingInformation.screenSize.width * 0.15,
                  left: sizingInformation.screenSize.width * 0.15,
                  child: Card(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    elevation: 10.0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: (sizingInformation.screenSize.height * 0.55),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Some cool text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                      fontSize: Constants.height / 70,
                      fontFamily: 'Exo2',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Some cool text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: const Color(0xFF000000),
                        fontSize: Constants.height / 70,
                        fontFamily: 'Exo2',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                // Search
                IconButton(
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/images/group_9.svg',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      widget.comingFromLogin
                          ? Navigator.push(context,
                              SlideRightRoute(page: SearchFoodPage()))
                          : _loginPopUp();
                    }),

                // Add Event
                IconButton(
                  icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/images/group_26.svg',
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    widget.comingFromLogin
                        ? Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Events()))
                        : _loginPopUp();
                  },
                ),

                // Profile
                IconButton(
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/images/group_8.svg',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      widget.comingFromLogin
                          ? Navigator.push(context,
                              SlideLeftRoute(page: ProfileDrawer()))
                          : _loginPopUp();
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this library: [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper), stack layout

```
Swiper(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new Image.network(
      "http://via.placeholder.com/288x188",
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  },
  itemCount: 10,
  itemWidth: 300.0,
  layout: SwiperLayout.STACK,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. So if you look at the example and flutter_swiper both has a bit differece. The stack side of flutter_swiper is on left where I want it to be on right. I am not able cotomize it. I left a comment on a issue too.
https://github.com/best-flutter/flutter_swiper/issues/52#issuecomment-620550202